# Вопрос по Join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Я сделал 2 вида запроса которые теоритический должны выдавать одинаковый результат. Но в практике оказалось не так.

**Запрос 1**

```
Select count(*) from Table1 t1 
Inner Join Table2 t2 On t1.id = t2.t1Id
```

**Запрос 2**

```
Select count(*) from Table1 t1
Inner Join Table2 t2 On t1.id = t2.t1Id 
Left Join Table3 t3 On t2.id = t3.t2Id
Left Join Table4 t4 On t3.id = t4.t3Id
```

Первый запрос выводит на 4 строки меньше данных чем второй запрос. Как это можно объяснить?

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что они должны выдавать одинаковые результаты? Вы в этих запросах не только пользуетесь разными джойнами, но даже и разными таблицами

Comment: LEFT JOIN берет записи для которых нет соответствия

Comment: @2ray, Но там стоит `INNER JON`, а это значит что он отрезает все остальные строки. Не так-ли?

Comment: @ШыназАлиш Только в первом запросе, во втором LEFT и разные таблицы

Answer (score 1):

Пример

t1

1

t2

2 1

t3

3 2

4 2

первый запрос  вернет 1 значение 1-2-1
второй запрос вернет  2 значения 1-2-1-3-2, 1-2-1-4-2

"Первый запрос выводит на 4 строки меньше данных чем второй запрос. Как это можно объяснить" объяснить это можно наличием  данных в 3 таблице где t2.id = t3.t2Id

Answer (score 0):

Если поле t3.t2Id или t4.t3Id  неуникальное,  то НИКАКИМ магическим образом эти запросы не дадут одинаковый результат.

p.s.  id поля-то хоть уникальные?

Comment: Да, вы правильно думаете, они уникальные.

Comment: а что с первой частью моего ответа